# Почему componentWillMount/componentWillUpdate могут вызваться несколько раз?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Вопрос следующий, читал про данную тему, нашёл что-то про реакт Fiber, но хорошего примера и объяснения не нашёл.

Почему componentWillMount/componentWillUpdate могут быть вызваны несколько раз.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я помню, такое может быть из-за асинхронщины.

Скажем:

```
componentWillMount(){
    // здесь какой-то промис/асинхронный вызов
    callAsyncFunction().then((data) => {
        this.setState({
            myValue: 'hello there'
        });
    });    
}
```

Для таких вещей лучше использовать `componentDidMount`.

Можно ещё [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41612993/1991579) почитать.

А вообще в React Fiber много чего внутри переписали. Почитать можно [тут](https://github.com/acdlite/react-fiber-architecture). Они там ввели понятие "приоритезации". Что может приводиться к весьма неоднозначным результатам.